# How can I "wait" until a user begins to actually move before I continue the program in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, core-location, core-motion, swift5

I am working on updating a drag racing app I had on the App Store. Previously the user would hit the "start" button, a countdown would begin and after the timer hit 0 the app would track the various things needed for racing. For instance how long the user takes to hit 60 MPH, 1/8 mile and a 1/4 mile. However I am adding a setting that allows the user to hit the start button, and then launch whenever they would like. When the app senses motion it begins to track the motion just as it would wisen the timer hit 0 in the previous version. However I am confused on the best method to use in order to "wait" until the app senses motion before tacking the information. I tried the following:

```
if(zeroTosixtyStyle == true){
        Warninglabel.text = ("Launch when you are ready!")
        repeat {
            sleep(UInt32(0.01))
        }while(locationManager.location?.speed ?? 0 < 2 );

        processTwo()

    }else{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector:
        #selector(ZerotoSixtyViewController.DecupdateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        DecupdateCounter()
    }
```

However this is obviously not a good solution. Ad it ramps up CPU usage, and makes certain parts of the app unresponsive. Using the method actually makes the "Warninglabel" I have not actually update to the string before the loop starts. What is a more efficient way to wait until the app senses motion in order to move onto "processTwo()"?

For more info the "zeroTosixtyStyle" is a boolean set by user settings. If its true the app waits for the user to launch, if it's false it runs the countdown. This works correctly.

Comment: You're right about not wanting to lock any threads or use `sleep` - but what type of input are you waiting for? A swipe or tap? If so, just add the gesture recognizer and then when it gets triggered, perform the action you want to do.

Comment: @George_E Sorry about the confusion. Im actually waiting for the speed to increase from < 1.

Comment: Is this SpriteKit?

Comment: No this is using CoreLocation, using the users GPS

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Just don't let anything change until that condition is met, and it will appear that the app is paused/waiting?

Comment: Yes exactly, and then as soon as it senses that condition, the program can move on

Comment: You don't want the app execution to stop. You just stop things changing you don't want to change. Like you could stop setting the text for a label until the condition is met.